# Running gcov on a program with arguments

Tags: c, gcov

I am trying to get gcov to run from the terminal on a program that has arguments.

Running the command  "gcov ./program" works but shows me coverage on the program with no inputs.
I am trying to run the command "gcov ./program -e file1 file2"
I believe its getting caught up on -e by taking it as a gcov flag or just getting tripped up on everything after ./programm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You compile your program with -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage flags. 
Example:

> gcc -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage -o sample tprogram.c

Then you run your program with any number of arguments you want. Example:

> ./sample 1 2 3

After this two new files with extension .gcno and .gcda will be created.Then run gcov on your program. Example:

> gcov tprogram.c

This will generate your required coverage report.